# Why is usePage().props not updated after Inertia.post?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a component to search a user. The controller in Laravel looks like this:

```
public function find(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $identifier = trim($request->input('identifier'));

    $id = $this->simpleUserSearch->find($identifier);

    if (empty($id)) {
        session()->flash('error', 'No logs for this user found, sorry!');
        return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.index');
    }

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.show', ['user' => $id]);
}
```

In the `HandleInertiaRequests` Middleware I am storing the session error like this:

```
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    $isAdmin = Auth::user() instanceof Admin;
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'csrf' => csrf_token(),
        'session' => [
            'notification' => session('notification'),
            'error' => session('error'),
        ],
        'auth' => self::share_auth(Auth::user()),
    ]);
}
```

On my front end component, I am using this method to trigger the search request

```
function search() {
  Inertia.post('/dashboard/users/find', {identifier: key.value})
  console.log(usePage().props.value.session.error);
  error.value = usePage().props.value.session.error;
}
```

When the search was not successful, the `usePage().props.value.session.error` will be still null, although when I check with VueInspector I see that it should have a value:
[image]

When I make another search requests, then `usePage().props.value.session.error` wil get the previsous error assigned..? Why is it not assigned on the first request?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the `Inertia.post` call did not cause a re-render of the component and thus the `usePage()` remained with the old value `null`.

The `Inertia.post` will only assure that the parent page component is re-rendered (sub-components are only re-rendered if a value changes). Therefore, its best to change error on re-render and pass it to the subcomponent. Once can use the `onUpdated` hook which is called after rendering. Something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <UserSearchBar :error="error"/>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// ..imports
const error = ref(null);

onUpdated(() => {
    console.log('updated parent');
    error.value = usePage().props.value.session.error;
})
```

Inside the subcomponent, the error is now a prop:

```
definedProps(['error']);

function search() {
  Inertia.post('/dashboard/users/find', {identifier: key.value})
  // console.log(usePage().props.value.session.error); <-removed
  // error.value = usePage().props.value.session.error; <-removed
}
```